# router route break after ng-build command

Tags: angular

I build a new Angular app, that work perfectly on my local machine with ng-serve, after using `ng build --aot --prod` and run the app with `http-server` one of the route is broken and return `404`.

When I get to the specific url, I see **2 GET** request. the first one pass and the second one return `404`.

What can cause that one route not to work after ng build?

Comment: Do you get any error while building the app?

Comment: many of the times it's variable used in the template that is not defined in component typescript file. But there could be many other reasons. Look the errors you get while building the app or please provide more info.

Comment: I dont get any errors while building the app